# Better Way to do this in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock

I'm just seeking some guidance on how to do this better. I was just doing some basic research to compare Monday's opening and low. The code code returns two lists, one with the returns (Monday's close - open/Monday's open) and a list that's just 1's and 0's to reflect if the return was positive or negate.

Please take a look as I'm sure there's a better way to do it in pandas but I just don't know how.

```
#Monday only
m_list = [] #results list
h_list = [] #hit list (close-low > 0)
n=0 #counter variable
for t in history.index:
    if datetime.datetime.weekday(t[1]) == 1: #t[1] is the timestamp in multi index (if timestemp is a Monday)
    x = history.ix[n]['open']-history.ix[n]['low']
    m_list.append((history.ix[n]['open']-history.ix[n]['low'])/history.ix[n]['open'])
    if x > 0:
        h_list.append(1)
    else:
        h_list.append(0)
    n += 1 #add to index counter
else:
    n += 1  #add to index counter 

print("Mean: ", mean(m_list), "Max: ", max(m_list),"Min: ", 
  min(m_list), "Hit Rate: ", sum(h_list)/len(h_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by straight forward :

`(history['open']-history['low'])>0`

This will give you `true` for rows where `open` is greater and `flase` where `low` is greater.

And if you want `1,0`, you can multiply the above statement with 1.

`((history['open']-history['low'])>0)*1`

## Example

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.random(10),
                  'b':np.random.random(10)})
```

Printing the data frame:

```
print(df)

    a   b
0   0.675916    0.796333
1   0.044582    0.352145
2   0.053654    0.784185
3   0.189674    0.036730
4   0.329166    0.021920
5   0.163660    0.331089
6   0.042633    0.517015
7   0.544534    0.770192
8   0.542793    0.379054
9   0.712132    0.712552
```

To make a new column `compare` where it is 1 if `a` is greater and 9 if `b` is greater :

```
df['compare'] = (df['a']-df['b']>0)*1
```

this will add new column `compare`:

```
    a   b   compare
0   0.675916    0.796333    0
1   0.044582    0.352145    0
2   0.053654    0.784185    0
3   0.189674    0.036730    1
4   0.329166    0.021920    1
5   0.163660    0.331089    0
6   0.042633    0.517015    0
7   0.544534    0.770192    0
8   0.542793    0.379054    1
9   0.712132    0.712552    0
```

Comment: Thanks, so would it be better to do it this way then extract the data that lands on Mondays?

Comment: it is better and easier to use the inbuilt way of working with columns in pandas than to work row-wise as you did in your code. This is clear and understandable at least, perhaps also faster. You easily add new columns and do operations to the columns as shown above.